# lxml attributes require full namespace

Tags: python, xml, excel, lxml

The code below reads the a table from an Excel 2003 XML workbook using lxml (python 3.3). The code works fine, however in order to access the Type attribute of the Data element via the get() method I need to use the key '{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Type' - why is this, I've specified this namespace with the ss prefix.

All I can think of is this namespace appears twice in the document, once with a namespace prefix and once without i.e.

```
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
```

And in the file the element and attribute are declared as below - The Type attribute with ss: prefix and the Cell and Data element with no prefix. However the declaration says both belong to the same schema 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet' so surely the parser should treat them equivalently?

```
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">QB11128020</Data></Cell>
```

My code:

```
with (open(filename,'r')) as f:
    doc = etree.parse(f)

namespaces={'o':'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office',
            'x':'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel',
            'ss':'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet'}

ws = doc.xpath('/ss:Workbook/ss:Worksheet', namespaces=namespaces)
if len(ws) > 0: 
    tables = ws[0].xpath('./ss:Table', namespaces=namespaces)
    if len(tables) > 0: 
        rows = tables[0].xpath('./ss:Row', namespaces=namespaces)
        for row in rows:
            cells = row.xpath('./ss:Cell/ss:Data', namespaces=namespaces)
            for cell in cells:
                print(cell.text);
                print(cell.keys());
                print(cell.get('{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Type'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [The lxml.etree Tutorial -- Namespace](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces):

> The ElementTree API avoids namespace prefixes wherever possible and
>   deploys the real namespaces (the URI) instead:

---

BTW, following

```
cell.get('{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Type')
```

can be written as:

```
cell.get('{%(ss)s}Type' % namespaces)
```

or:

```
cell.get('{{{0[ss]}}}Type'.format(namespaces))
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess the key point is I'm using the ElementTree api to access the attribute, but XPath to access the Elements?

Comment: @user2981639, I don't understand your question in the comment. Do you want something like `for data_type in row.xpath('./ss:Cell/ss:Data/@ss:Type', namespaces=namespaces): print data_type` ?

Comment: It's more a statement rather than a question, I'd expect to be able to access the element and attributes consistantly, i.e. either prefixing with ss: or the full namespace. In my sample code I have to prefix the element with ss: in my xpath query but when I access the attribute of that element I have to use the {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet} syntax. It's not really an issue but seems a little unusual as I've never used an xml parser with this syntax before.